# Palestinian politicians speaking against Hamas

Tags: palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, hamas, opposition

From [*Ex-Hamas minister: 'People in Gaza say that Sinwar and his men destroyed us'*](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/israel-at-war/1702235745-ex-hamas-minister-people-in-gaza-say-that-sinwar-and-his-men-destroyed-us):

> According to a Shin Bet investigation, Yousef Almansi, the former Hamas communications minister, criticized the Hamas leadership and its leader Yahya Sinwar, Israel's sworn enemy.
>
> "It's a group of madmen that Sinwar leads. They wiped out the Gaza Strip and set it back 200 years," he says.
>
> “People in the Gaza Strip say that Sinwar and his men destroyed us, we must get rid of them.”
>
> "I haven't seen anyone in the Gaza Strip supporting Sinwar, no one likes him. There are people who, day and night, pray for God to free us from him," he said.

Have any other Palestinian leaders voiced criticism of Hamas? I am particularly interested in those affiliated with the Palestinian Authority or non-affiliated, since they may be potential candidates for the future post-Hamas Gaza government.

Comment: Voting not to close - It's a simple question asking if any influential Palestinian has criticised Hamas. This can be answered factually with verifiable source.

Comment: Are you looking for someone interested in making peace with Israel? Because "Hamas are incompetents in their attempts to end Israel" is also a perfectly valid criticism of Hamas.

Comment: @ZevSpitz fair point. I am interested in those who have the well-being of Palestinians at heart - this likely implies some form of peaceful coexistence with Israel, but not necessarily a formal agreement. By now ME peacemaking has become somewhat like resistance - a thing that supports itself for the sake of itself, making careers and comfortable living for those involved.

Comment: @RogerV. What do Palestinians perceive as their own well-being? They may view Israel's existence as so fundamentally at odds with their own value system as to render everything else meaningless.

Comment: @ZevSpitz in every society there is a fraction of fanatics, who take the value system taught to them literally, but most people have the same [hierarchy of needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs). It is just that in some societies the value system is better aligned to the actual needs.

Comment: @RogerV. "Another criticism is that people will only go up this pyramid when most of the time people are going up and down this pyramid all the time." People often choose to forgo lower needs in favor of satisfying higher needs. 82% of West Bank Palestinians & 57% of Gazans believe Hamas made the right choice in attacking, in spite of the consequences. https://pcpsr.org/en/node/963

Answer (score 7):

> Have any other Palestinian leaders voiced criticism of Hamas?

### PFLP

Lots of "Palestinian leaders" voiced criticism of Hamas, Israel targets these organizations with priority to bolster the presence of Hamas: a militancy unlikely to receive international solidarity.

> Rabah Muhanna a senior official in the Popular Front to Liberate Palestine (PFLP) strongly criticized Hamas on Saturday over the way it rules the Gaza Strip since mid June 2007. In a statement to the press, Muhanna accused Hamas of failing to achieve the political partnership with other political factions, and taking exclusive procession of the Strip aiming at imposing its Islamic ideology on the coastal region. - [IEMC](https://imemc.org/article/56691/),

And,

> PFLP official Rabah Muhanna was one of many faction leaders who also called upon Hamas to sever relations with the Muslim Brotherhood. [Palestine Chronicle](https://www.palestinechronicle.com/pflp-hamas-should-not-abandon-ideology/)

And to the extent that there is an unvoiced criticism,

> "We have tried, so let them now try [...] it is their turn." - [George Habash](https://electronicintifada.net/content/george-habashs-contribution-palestinian-struggle/7332)

My interpretation is that the PFLP had largely fallen apart, though they still exist [and have a functioning militia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Ali_Mustafa_Brigades). And the new form of resistance was both *different* and not something that would garner support from the PFLP.

### Fatah (PLO)

On the other side, lots of the Palestinian elected leaders have expressed disagreement with Hamas. These organizations are largely rejected by Palestinians because though advocating for peaceful reform and discouraging militancy, they've largely gained nothing and only given concessions. Their presence as a functioning government is more of a PR stunt by Israel itself. For example, the [PLO cut off funding for the PFLP](https://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Palestinian-Authoritys-Abbas-suspends-funds-to-PLO-terror-group-450886), and was likely party to or responsible for the [assassination of a PFLP member in the Palestinian embassy in Bulgaria.](https://www.mintpressnews.com/mossad-implicated-assasination-bulgaria/221236/)

- Arafat had the leader of Hamas placed under house arrest, and other senior officials arrested. [source](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2002/jun/25/israel).
- "Nobody will dodge [Hamas's] responsibility. ... We didn’t want or need this war. What was the point? Did Hamas imagine that it could win?" - [Mahmoud Habbash](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world/abbas-aide-hamas-will-not-be-able-to-dodge-responsibility-for-what-s-happening-in-gaza/ar-AA1lKBle)
- Hamas's policies and actions "do not represent the Palestinian people" - [Mahmoud Abbas](https://www.timesofisrael.com/abbas-says-hamas-actions-dont-represent-palestinians-then-seems-to-backtrack/)

Comment: I downvoted because you are quoting content from more than a *decade* back where as the Q is asking about the situation *now*. Most know that PLO and Hamas have even fought a war in the past. But today (till the war happened) PLO and Hamas were actually in discussion about how they could work together.

Comment: @sfxedit But if the quoted people still live it might be that they still hold the expressed views. Even old quotes are better than no quotes. And that's the big problem with this answer, no date stamps given.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I'd agree if their views had not *evolved*, which it clearly has as they were now talking with each other. How relevant are the older views of the PLO founder and the Likud Party founder, to current times, given that they were both once terrorists?

Comment: @sfxedit [politics.se] is about matters of policy. The article is two weeks old. If you're looking for current events, this is certainly not the best place to ask. It's also not evident from the question that any specific time frame is required, and I'm not sure what "now" is supposed to mean when things haven't changed. As a matter of policy the PLO and PFLP have not realigned since the Hamas attack. Their alignment with or against Hamas whatever it was before the conflict has not changed. These quotes are still relevant.

Comment: @EvanCarroll *I'm not sure what "now" is supposed to mean when things haven't changed.* What has changed is that Israel has now gone from supporting Hamas (to divide the Palestine polity) to declaring it its enemy and invading Gaza.  ... Note that the question asks - *I am particularly interested in those affiliated with the Palestinian Authority or non-affiliated, **since they may be potential candidates for the future post-Hamas Gaza government**.* Do you genuinely believe that these people will be guided by what they said 10+ years ago, amidst a very different political scenario today?

Comment: On paper, Fatah may "advocat[e] for peaceful reform and discouraging militancy", but they're still incentivizing terror by paying salaries & guaranteeing employment to those who have served in Israeli prisons for terror; they've done nothing to ameliorate the antisemitism/anti-Zionism in PA-controlled media & education. The results speak for themselves. https://www.jns.org/israel-palestinianconflict/terrorism/23/7/18/303552/

Comment: @ZevSpitz you could make the same argument about Israel itself, which is the state and controlling apparatus behind the IDF which is also engaged in "incentivizing terror by paying salaries & guaranteeing employment to those who have served in Israeli prisons."

Comment: @EvanCarroll Not really. Nobody in the IDF gets any sort of payment structure or benefits for going and killing random people; they get a military court trial or committed to an insane asylum.

Comment: The IDF is paying all their enlistees now, and they're literally killing random people. Over 10,000 (by their own numbers). These are people they don't intend to kill, right? It's literally random. You drop a bomb on a hospital, you kill people at random that are at a hospital.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The IDF is not paying its personnel for random people to be killed but for hitting military targets embedded within the civilian population; it's taken great pains to warn civilians about its actions. Thus: no intent to kill. Do you think any of the people imprisoned by Israel for acts of terror had any military goal in mind, other than killing random civilians?

Comment: @ZevSpitz this isn't the view of the international community, or the US president. Sounds like a conspiracy theory. Do you think any of the people imprisoned by Israel? Most of them are not charged, never mind convicted. We'll never know.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's a matter of numbers. According to https://euromedmonitor.org/en/article/5908/Israel-hits-Gaza-Strip-with-the-equivalent-of-two-nuclear-bombs , Israel has dropped over 25,000 tons of explosives on the Gaza Strip. If we accept the Hamas casualty figures at face value, that's more than a ton of explosives per person on average. More than double that, if we factor in IDF estimates of Hamas personnel killed (8,500).

Comment: @ZevSpitz and what part of that substantiates your argument that the IDF is not a terrorist organization? They come from a terrorist organization -- we can agree on that right? Irgun was certainly a terrorist organization. And, now they're a  terrorist organization with tens of thousands of tons of explosives (potentially the most dangerous terrorist organization), which claims that because of its war with Hamas it can drop 25,000 tons of explosives on the people of Gaza. And to put that into perspective, a [1 ton bomb destroys a city block.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yvm2z6XMXMw)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I claimed that the IDF doesn't target random/arbitrary civilians, or civilians at all, but rather aims specifically for military targets & takes great pains to avoid civilians; & is therefore not a terrorist organization. Do you think Israel's aim is so miserably bad that it needs two tons of explosives to kill a single person, on average? Obviously Israel is taking extraordinary pains to avoid civilians. This behavior stands in blinding contrast to Hamas, which since Oct. 7 has fired more than 12,000 unguided rockets in the general direction of Israeli cities.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Irgun may or may not have been a terrorist organization 75 years ago, but the IDF is accountable to civilian authorities - executive, legislature, & judiciary - who've all made it abundantly clear that Hamas is the target, not Gazan civilians.

Comment: "may or may not"? Dude, even Israel has accepted Irgun was a terrorist organization. And having "civilian authorities - executive, legislature, & judiciary" is not even a criteria for a terrorist organization. Terrorism is "Criminal acts intended or calculated to **provoke a state of terror in the general public, a group of persons or particular persons for political purposes"**. Having the agreement of  the state whose army is committing the terror doesn't make it _not_ terrorism.

Comment: I can't see how telling civilians to go to an area you're bombing isn't terrorism. Israel has a pattern of this behavior. Literally bombing the corridors they claim are safe. https://youtu.be/gm31L-BaGIM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150700/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-evan-carroll).

Answer (score 0):

[One recent example (according to Israeli Ynetnews)](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/sk92ow9wa?utm_source=taboola&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=internal):

> Osama al-Ali, the Palestinian ambassador to Oman and a member of the Palestinian National Council advising the Fatah movement, sharply criticized Hamas, saying they made a mistake and brought "100 catastrophes on Gaza."

The al-Ali position expressed more specifically is:

> "We begged for reconciliation with Hamas from day one because **we feared that day (October 7). Hamas led to 100 catastrophes in Gaza,"** said al-Ali. When asked why the Palestinian Authority remains silent about what Hamas did and even supports it publicly, Osama replied, "The answer changes depending on who is doing the asking. When we talk to Israelis, we will tell them, 'You’re criminals and murderers.' **But we will also place responsibility on those who made mistakes and brought about these results in Gaza."**
>
> Al-Ali added, "**The question that remains unanswered is why Hamas’ leaders left Gaza. Why are rockets launched from Gaza toward Israel when the known launchers aren’t being hit by Israeli missiles?** We have many questions, but we’re waiting for the right time to ask them, not right now."