# Have any Israeli leaders condemned calls for genocide and expulsion?

Tags: israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, genocide

I recently came across [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83401/palestinian-politicians-speaking-against-hamas) question on this website which set me thinking about the converse.

There are many examples of prominent Israeli personalities, from politics, military and media, calling for the genocide of Palestinians and / or the explusion of the entire population of Gaza. For example, Likud party MP, Galit Distel Atbaryan, [called for](https://www.commondreams.org/news/israel-gaza-genocide) the

> erasing all of Gaza from the face of the Earth

Similarly, former military office Eliyahu Yossian [said](https://twitter.com/clashreport/status/1718989457171329383):

> There is no population in Gaza, there are 2.5 million terrorists.
> There is no meaning to give them warning missiles.

From the media, journalist Shimon Riklin [said](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/chris-hayes-warns-there-is-no-terrorist-attack-no-matter-how-horrific-that-can-wash-clean-what-we-are-seeing-in-gaza/ar-AA1lMXn3):

> I am for the war crimes. I don’t care if I am criticized, and I
> honestly don’t care. I am unable to sleep if I do not see houses being
> destroyed in Gaza

Has there been condemnation by an Israeli cabinet minister for such comments and calls? I am aware that there was some push back when cabinet minister Amihai Eliyahu [suggested](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/world/controversial-remarks-from-the-israeli-minister-the-nuclear-bomb-is-an-option/ar-AA1jtMvO) that using a nuclear weapon on Gaza could be an option, but are there any other examples?

Comment: The title says "Israeli leaders", but the question body says "senior Israeli politicians". Can you clarify who exactly you're looking for statements from? What counts as a "senior politician" and/or "leader"? Would a member of the Knesset (as in Raveesh's answer) count?

Comment: @F1Krazy, good point. I had in mind mainly cabinet ministers. I have now edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: There has been a question about Palestinian leaders condemning Hamas, so this is a perfectly valid question. Downvoters/close voters should explain their reasons.

Comment: The converse of the referenced question would be "did Israeli politicians criticize Israel's actions as damaging to Israel". The true converse of your question is ["Did Palestinian leaders condemned Palestinian acts towards Israelis/Jews as inherently wrong or immoral?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83694/did-palestinian-leaders-publicly-condemn-oct-7th-atrocities-as-immoral).

Comment: Voting not to close - This question can be factually answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having not received a satisfactory answer, I decided to look into this. After extensive searching, I was unable to find any examples of cabinet ministers condemning calls for genocide.

Morover, the example I cite in the question, that of Amihai Eliyahu, turned out also to not be a condemnation. After Amihai suggested dropping an atomic bomb on Gaza was an option, the most that was said is response by a cabinet minister (that I could find), was Benjamin Netanyahu's [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amihai_Eliyahu#cite_note-17) that his remarks were "divorced from reality". [He was initially suspended from the cabinet, but then allowed to take part via phone](https://www.timesofisrael.com/rabbi-backs-remark-by-his-son-a-far-right-minister-that-nuking-gaza-is-an-option/) . As the cabinet has not regularly met in person since October the 7th, it appears that he has faced almost no pushback at all.

Hence, I conclude that there has been no condemnation by an Israeli cabinet minister of calls for genocide.

Comment: It is definitely not a compliment to say for a politician more or less "what are you smoking" (or "your talks completely diverge from reality"), in public. I would count this.

Comment: I count it as a rebuke. Condemnation requires a claim that the thing being condemned is _wrong_ rather than just _incorrect_.

Comment: Amihai Eliahu's remark, deplorable though it was, was still an off-hand remark, not an active suggestion. He was asked in a radio (I think) interview: "What about an atomic bomb?" and retorted "Well, that could be a solution". To my knowledge, he has not brought this up at any other time.  The more serious and dangerous remarks are those by Netanyahu, Smotrich, Ben-Gvir and Gallant, plus former and current military officers - because the former call the shots in the government and the latter are close to the executing entity. Regardless of all that: +1, I have also not noticed a condemnation.

Comment: Perhaps Nethanyahu thought they were divorced from reality because Israel has not officially admitted to having atomic bombs...

Answer (score 6):

Ofer Cassif member of the Knesset from Israel's Hadash party on [8th October](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/10/8/israeli-lawmaker-blames-pogroms-against-palestinians-for-terrible-attacks) spoke to al Jazeera:

> We have been warning time and time again… everything is going to erupt and everybody is going to pay a price – mainly innocent civilians on both sides. And unfortunately, that is exactly what happened.
>
> The Israeli government, which is a fascist government, supports, encourages, and leads pogroms against the Palestinians. There is an ethnic cleansing going on. It was obvious the writing was on the wall, written in the blood of the Palestinians  – and unfortunately now Israelis as well.

Since he compared Israel's government's actions to Nazi Germany's [Final Solution](https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/politics-and-diplomacy/article-768978) he was suspended from the Knesset.

Note: *The Final Solution* is Nazi language — [Endlösung der Judenfrage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Solution) — for Genocide.

Comment: Ofer is a nice guy, but he is not a leader of Israel; he is a member of parliament from an joint Hebrew-Arab party/candidate list (that's Hadash). He is not perceived as a leader by the general public and often maligned in the media for being very assertive in his rejection of Israeli government policy.